# How can I stop my code from generating an infinite loop using scanf?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

This is a function that is being called from main. How can I make this code check for letter inputs, and go into the while loop when it detects an input that is NOT an integer? Thanks

```
int time1(void)
{
    int hour;

        printf("Enter the hour: ");
        scanf("%d", &hour);

            while (hour > MAX_HOUR || hour < MIN_HOUR) 
            {
                printf("Invalid hour input. Please enter an hour between 1 and 12: ");
                scanf("%d", &hour);
            }

            return hour;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test whether it succeeded or failed:

```
hour = -1;   // So you can detect afterwards if they never succeeded at all

while ( 1 == scanf("%d", &hour) )
{
    if ( hour >= MIN_HOUR && hour <= MAX_HOUR )
         break;

    printf("Invalid hour input, try again...");
}
```

That version will break if they type in `"hello"`, for example. If you want to keep asking them  after they type in garbage, then you have to clear all the garbage from the stream, e.g.:

```
for (;;)
{
    int result = scanf("%d", &hour);

    if ( result == EOF )
    {
        hour = -1;
        break;
    }

    if ( result != 1 )
    {
    // consume garbage which will end in a newline
        for (int ch; (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'; ) {}
        continue;
    }

    if ( hour >= MIN_HOUR && hour <= MAX_HOUR )
         break;

    printf("Invalid hour input, try again...");
}
```

It's not straightforward to do robust stream input in C!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
int time1(void) {

    int hour;

    printf("Enter the hour: ");
    scanf("%d", &hour);

    if(hour>='0' && hour<='9')
    {
        while (hour > MAX_HOUR || hour < MIN_HOUR)
        {
            printf("Invalid hour input. Please enter an hour between 1 and 12: ");
            scanf("%d", &hour);
        }
    }

    return hour;
}
```